# MakeFile: How to refer to source by position in body of rule?

Tags: makefile

Is there a way I can refer to the sources by their position in the body of the rule ? something like

```
targ: s1 s2 s3
        cmd $(1) foo $(2) bar $(3)
```

so that "make targ" runs "cmd s1 foo s2 bar s3" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
targ: s1 s2 s3
    cmd $(word 1,$^) foo $(word 2,$^) bar $(word 3,$^)
```